# VM Instance is not accessible The project you requested is unavailable

Tags: google-compute-engine

Just signed to the free Google cloud account (300$ Credit) to see if it supports exporting VMs in OVF format.

Created a new project and By clicking on the Compute>Compute engine> VM Instance I see below error message:

"The project you requested is unavailable."

There is no extra information provided on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Google compute engine currently doesn't support exporting VMs in OVF or OVA format. You can use free tools, e.g. VirtulBox to convert GCE images from the RAW format to VMD, VDI, VHD
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp58756992

Here are instructions of how to create a RAW file from an image:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#exporting_an_image_to_google_cloud_storage

In order to troubleshoot your GCE "The project you requested is unavailable" issue in developer console, you can login using Incognito window in chrome or use another browser to see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update: GCE supports OVA and OVF now. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-ovf-files) is how you can import the image.