# Deploying ova/ovf in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Can we deploy an OVA/OVF file in Google Compute Engine? Example, one of IBM's virtual appliance

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS9H2Y_6.0.1/com.ibm.dp.xi.doc/virtual_installationimage.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VM Instance is not accessible The project you requested is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285638/vm-instance-is-not-accessible-the-project-you-requested-is-unavailable)

Answer (score 2):

I understand you want to exports VMs in OVA or OVF format into GCE. As per [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/compute#iaas_comparison) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285638/vm-instance-is-not-accessible-the-project-you-requested-is-unavailable) compute engine support only RAW format. You may want to try with [converting OVA file into RAW format](http://opentox.github.io/installation/2012/08/02/converting-ova-images-to-kvm) using some free tools like VirtualBox or extracting files in RAW format.